# How do I edit my Airline config such that modified files will have a differently colored bar?

Tags: plugin-airline

I recently switched to base16_default dark as my color theme.  I love it, but it's the first theme I've used where a modified buffer's airline bar doesn't change color.

I do, however get the [+] symbol indicating the buffer has unsaved changes.

I've set my iterm2 colors to preset 'base16-default.dark', my vim theme to 'base-16-default' and my airline theme to [this](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline-themes/blob/master/autoload/airline/themes/base16_default.vim)